# in Jade, how I can output the contents of an `extends` block inside of a mixin?

Tags: block, pug, mixins, template-inheritance

How I can output the contents of an extends block inside of a mixin?

This is a simplified example:

mixins.jade

```
mixin form()
  form
    block
```

layout.jade

```
include mixins.jade

body
  +form
    block content
```

somepage.jade

```
extends layout
block content
  input(type=text)
```

Here I would like to achieve:

```
<form>
  <input type="text"></input>
</form>
```

But currently all I get is:

```
<form></form>
```

Comment: I created [this pull request](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/pull/1195) to add a failing test which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I want to confirm that the issue remains when no `include` is involved in layout.jade and the mixin is just written inline instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that did not work was [identified as a bug](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/pull/1195#issuecomment-25455329) after I had created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/1192) and submitted a [failing spec](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/pull/1195).

Per [this pull request](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/pull/1224) it's now possible to do what I described in my original question but [as stated](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/pull/1224#issuecomment-25521789), this currently only works in the development branch of Jade and will be a part of the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

layout.jade

```
doctype 5
  head 
    title "Title"
  body
    block content
      include mixins.jade
      +form
        block
```

SomePage.jade

```
extends layout
block content
  input(type=text)
```

Comment: This does not work. I've added a comment on my question which demonstrates the issue when there is no include involved.

Comment: That's odd, it worked locally for me using that.  I'll check it out later on tonight and try to replicate your error then fix it.